# Links are firing after jQuery sortables is stopped

Tags: jquery, sortables

My sortable list is a connected list with a bunch of links. The links should not fire when the user is sorting the list or after they let go of the mouse to stop sorting. With the following code, the links are not fired when sorted within the same list.  However, when you transfer the item over to the connected list then the link is clicked.  How can I prevent this?

```
    a("app_link:not(.ui-sortable-helper)").live("click", function () {

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating from jQuery UI 1.7.2 to 1.8+ fixed this issue.